# online url classifier

Tags: url, dns, classification

I want to write an online application that:

1. reads the URL from address bar of the browser
2. extracts its lexical features (like n-grams)
3. extracts its host based features (fetch DNS records online, its A, PTR, TTL fields)
4. classify the URL into malicious or benign (using machine learning)

Can anyone help me with 1 and 3?

Comment: Which language and platform will be the best to work with for the above application -  java or .NET ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this (application) is a task you can accomplish, as you can't really determine site content based on url.

See something like [Mozilla Phishing Protection Design Documentation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Phishing_Protection:_Design_Documentation) and  [Google Safe Browsing spec](http://code.google.com/p/google-safe-browsing/wiki/Protocolv2Spec) instead

Comment: this is a project based on a recent ACM publication.. it says we can classify sites using url alone..

Comment: Yes, you'll probably get some better-than-random results, but the security will still be bad *and* with false positives.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what language you may be looking at.

For Item 1 here is a .net library that maybe helpful

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx

Comment: a stand-alone java online application.